# Sonar Scanner coverage empty and test file analysis

Tags: jenkins, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

**Some context**

I am trying to configure the plugin 'Sonar Scanner' in our Jenkins, the trigger and the project validation is "working", I added the " " because it is actually validating everything, even the test files and it is not checking the coverage.

**Things you should know before**

- I have no access to Jenkins machine
- I have no access to SonarQube machine
- All plugins installed from Jenkins are the most recent versions

**My Config**

My project folder structure looks like this (Java project):

```
.git
.scannerwork
bl
commons
datafeed
keyfiles
persistence
post-aggregator
project-setup
webapp
webapp-server
.gitignore  
pom.xml
```

My Sonar Scanner config is:

```
#required metadata
sonar.projectKey=inventory
sonar.projectName=Inventory1
sonar.language=java
sonar.sourceEncoding=UTF-8
#sonar.tests=**/.*Test.java
sonar.exclusions=**/*Dto*, **/*Entity*
sonar.binaries=build/classes
sonar.java.binaries=/data/application/jenkins/jenkins/workspace/$JOB_NAME

#Adding more info to the log
sonar.verbose=true

#Path to source directory
sonar.sources=/data/application/jenkins/jenkins/workspace/$JOB_NAME
```

**The problems**

1. Test coverage is 0[image]
2. Checking the report I see that the current Scanner config checks everything, even the tests

So.. the questions are:

1. My test files are spread all around in the project, how can (or if it is even possible) to add a regex to the "sonar.tests"? i have been trying to do it but no success, all my tests ends with Test.java
2. How can I avoid properly Sonar to scan the test files.
3. Do I need jacoco as well in order to make this work or its possible to do it without it? (we are configuring the jacoco-maven in the project)

Thank you for your time!

Comment: You need to sent to SonarQube information about your unit test coverage like sonar.coverage.jacoco.xmlReportPaths=... check this: https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/analysis/coverage/

Comment: Hi @Peska thanks for the comment, the dev team will configure Jacoco and we will try this.